# Outlook Check Message Type

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32, win32com

I’m using a python package called `win32com` to directly access and scrape the inboxes from Outlook. As the Outlook application is setup to have multiple email accounts, I’ve had to adapt my code to read messages from multiple email accounts. However, the messages contains calendar invites and I just want email messages to be scraped. Is there a way to filter the messages based on type?

```
Outlook = client.Dispatch(“Outlook.Application”).GetNameSpace(“MAPI”)
Messages = outlook.Folders(“test@test.com).Folders(“Inbox”)

For msg in messages: 
    #Do Something
```

Comment: Haha, typo. Thanks for bringing it up. Edited to correct.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olobjectclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to check if the object is of type `OlObjectClass.olMail`, which is represented by value `43`. You can check all enumerations [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olobjectclass).

```
Outlook = client.Dispatch(“Outlook.Application”).GetNameSpace(“MAPI”)
Messages = outlook.Folders(“test@test.com).Folders(“Inbox”)

for msg in messages: 
    if msg.Class == 43: # OlObjectClass.olMail
        #Do Something
```

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful. Is there a way to check the type using isintance() and passing a named type? I just want to make it clear to other devs.

Comment: It does work as suggested. But my follow up question does remain. Also thanks op for the answer!

Comment: Please consider marking this as solved. As for the other question, you may start a new thread.